# Three numbers are being drawn from $\{0,\ldots,9\}$ twice, with replacement. What is the probability for match if discarding order?

Tags: probability

Three numbers are being drawn from $\{0,\ldots,9\}$ twice, with replacement. What is the probability for a match if discarding order?

**My solution**

Let
$$M=\{\text{match}\},\space A_i=\{i\text{ different numbers are being drawn}\}, \space i=1,2,3$$
Since $A_1, A_2, A_3$ are a partition of $S$, ***Law of Total Probability*** gives
$$P(M)=\sum_{i=1}^3P(M|A_i)P(A_i)$$
I think i've found the probabilities for $A_1, A_2, A_3$
$$P(A_1)=\frac{10}{10^3}, \space P(A_2)=\frac{10\cdot9}{10^3}, \space P(A_3)=\frac{10\cdot9\cdot8}{10^3}.$$
But I'm not sure how to assign probabilities for $M|A_1, M|A_2, M|A_3$. My thought was of how many ways you can order a set of three elements given that $A_1, A_2$ or $A_3$ occurs. If that is correct, then
$$P(M|A_1)=\frac{1}{10^3}, \space P(M|A_2)=\frac{3}{10^3}, \space P(M|A_3)=\frac{3!}{10^3}.$$
Leads to
$$P(M)=\frac{10+10\cdot9\cdot3+10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot3!}{10^6}=0.0046.$$
But my professors answer was:
$$(10+3\cdot3\cdot90+720\cdot6)/1000^2=0.00514.$$

Comment: If you draw twice, how do you draw three numbers?

Comment: Draw three numbers twice, and look for a match.

Comment: To clarify... am I correct in understanding that you first draw three numbers with replacement... take note of what they are... let's call them $a,b,c$.  Then, we draw three numbers yet again... take note of what they are... lets call these now $A,B,C$.  You now ask what the probability is that the multiset $\{a,b,c\}$ is the same as the multiset $\{A,B,C\}$?  (*e.g. if I draw a $5,5,8$ the first time and I draw an $8,5,5$ the second time it counts as a perfect match?*)

Comment: ahhhh, ^THAT^ is much clearer.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: This doesn't affect the answer since you do it consistently, but I think you have the definitions of $A_1$ and $A_3$ swapped.

Comment: Yes @eyeballfrog, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in $P(A_2)$. While that is the probability of drawing any specific ordering of $aab$, you could also draw them in $aba$ order and $baa$ order.

Comment: Yes thanks, $P(A_2)=\frac{3\cdot10\cdot9}{10^3}$ will do. Then $P(M|A_2)$ means that my other set could be ordered in 3 ways?